# how to add custom logo to my template

Tags: customization, css, logo

So now it should be somewhere here. I still have no idea how to do it :<

```
<div id="logo-wrap">
        <?php


            PC_Utility::pc_display_theme_logo($options);

            $options = get_option( PC_OPTIONS_DB_NAME );
            if ( !isset($options[ 'chk_hide_description' ]) ) { ?>
                <div id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>

    </div><!-- #logo-wrap -->
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in your code: `<div id="logo-wrap"><?php` the `<?php` doesn't have any purpose there, and doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: Well, as long as you don't provide us with the PC_Utility class function `pc_display_theme_logo`, there's nothing we can do to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This line.

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/logoname" />
```

TO

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/YOURLOGO.jpg" />
```

Make sure "YOURLOGO.jpg" is in your themes images folder first otherwise it won't work.